# can Wi-fi network strength (dBm) come in a positive value?

Tags: android, iphone, windows, linux

Sorry for the probably dummy question but I'm lost.
can Wi-fi network strength (dBm) come in a positive value?
is there any reference that depicts this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually not. See [dBm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm). It's a way to describe power relative to one milliwatt (1mW). 
If the received power is more than that one mW, the value is positive, if it is exactly 1mW it's 0. It's negative if the power is below 1mW.

Wifi reception strengths as a power are usually lower than 1mW. Hence the value is usually negative *(that wikipedia link states -10dBm and downwards)*.